# How does vampirism work, if it existed in real life?

Tags: vampires

In specifics, how fast, how painful, and in what order would the human body be infected, specifically from being bitten on the neck. I have found some information, but there are still pieces missing. please take care in answering with facts.(well, not facts, vampires supposedly don't exist.)

Comment: Some books, such as Bram Stoker's Dracula, put the vampiric conversion at weeks to months.  Other stories, movies, and role playing games put the conversion at overnight to a few minutes or even nearly instantly. Without further constraint, it works at the speed of plot.

Comment: Given that vampirism isn't real, and fictional descriptions of it vary enormously, what were you really expecting here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realistic Vampire Virus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109093/realistic-vampire-virus)

Comment: as @Ghedipunk stated, speed would be as the plot requires. how painful? what are you looking for, do the internal organs and bones need to be redistributed, or do teeth just elongate? order of infection, depends on your idea for transmission. does a victim need to be bitten o the neck, or on the little toe during a full moon in July? without specific details, this cannot be answered as is.

Comment: Following the edits, I'd say this is now a proper duplicate of the question @SRM-ReinstateMonica linked.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the setting. Culturally vampires will find their roots in religious beliefs and so in the oldest stories such as Dracula it’s ultimately falls to God vs Satan and that impacts on how Dracula is portrayed and behaves. In more contemporary works vampirism is often described as an actual disease of sorts, like in Elder Scrolls or Blade I where a vampire describes it to Blade as a sort of cancer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what types of vampire you speak of are the vampires alive like in the show Supernatural or or they the classic undead vampires.
Acording to Supernatural even after bit and infected you do not FULLY turn into a vampire until you drink your first blood
Acording to the Skyrim wiki and I quote 
"If the disease has not been cured (via a Cure Disease potion or praying at a shrine) within three days, the infection mutates into full vampirism, causing a series of maladaptive and beneficial traits to emerge in the subject. Drinking blood can stay the infection and lessen the deficits of the disease."
In most the show Supernatural it's almost instantly.
According to MOST Popular stuff the subject is infected, gets sick and dies with in a day of infection upon there death they reanimate as a vampire. 
In Dungeons and dragons upon being bit you are turned into a vampire spawn, and the vampire who turned you must turn you into a true vampire. Hope that helps.